# Gurobi: how to add a constraint x1*x2*x3

Tags: java, python, linear-programming, gurobi

I wish to add a constraint `n1 = x1 * x2 *x3` in Gurobi, where `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are variables with 0 or 1. Unfortunately, can not find the solution.

Can someone help me?

Comment: x1 are binary value? Eg : 10101. You want to multiply them?

Comment: @CycDemo actually x1 x2, x3 all are just 0 or 1. And yes, multiply them

Comment: Can you verbalize your constraint in terms of IF, THEN, ELSE, AND, OR, XOR, NOT. The example you gave is IF x1 AND x2 AND x3, THEN n1, ELSE NOT n1. Less strictly, you gave, if x1, x2, and x3 all equal 1 then n1 equal 1 else n1 equals 0.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to create a seemingly non-linear constraint on binary variables.  You can model this as a series of linear constraints by noting the `n` will have the value 1 if and only if x1, x2, and x3 are all 1.

```
// only if part
model.addConstr(n, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, x1);
model.addConstr(n, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, x2);
model.addConstr(n, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, x3);

// if part
GRBLinExpr all_three;
all_three.addTerm(1.0, x1);
all_three.addTerm(1.0, x2);
all_three.addTerm(1.0, x3);
all_three.addConstrant(-2);
model.addConstr(n, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, all_three);
```

This adds the constraints
`n >= x1 + x2 + x3 - 2` and `n <= min(x1, x2, x3)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a more complicated one. for example : n3=x2* (n1+n2- n1*n2) +x1* (n1-n2) *(n1-n2), then how to deal with it? here all variables are all 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
n1<=x1
n1<=x2
n1<=x3
2+n1>=x1+x2+x3
```

If any of the of the x are 0, then n will be force to zero. If all are 1, n is forced to 1.

**Edit**
Since Gurobi recognizes binary variables, you could just use

```
3*n1<=x1+x2+x3
2+n1>=x1+x2+x3
```

The first only allow 0 and 1 while this would allow fractional values if not for the binary requirement.

**EDIT**
The constraint

```
n3 = x2 * (n1 + n2 - n1 * n2) + x1 * (n1 - n2) *(n1 - n2)
```

appears to be trying to enforce the logic

```
IF n1 AND n2: 
    n3 = x2

IF n1 XOR n2:
    n3 = x1

IF (NOT n1) AND (NOT n2):
    n3 = 0
```

Since it the standard rule for [expressing boolean logic operations in zero-one integer linear programming (ILP)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12118) take the form of `x1 AND x2 IMPLIES y1`, I reconstructed the above to read

```
n1 AND n2 IMPLIES i1
n1 XOR n2 IMPLIES i2
(NOT n1) AND (NOT n2) IMPLIES i3
```

Constructing the constraints for `i1, i2, i3` is given below

```
IF n1 AND n2, THEN i1 
    i1 ≥ n1 + n2 − 1
    i1 ≤ n1
    i1 ≤ n2
    0 ≤ i1 ≤ 1

IF n1 XOR n2, THEN i2
    i2 ≤ n1 + n2
    i2 ≥ n1 − n2
    i2 ≥ n2 − n1
    i2 ≤ 2 − n1 − n2
    0 ≤ i2 ≤ 1

IF NOT n1 AND NOT n2, THEN i3
    i3 ≥ 1 - n1 - n2
    i3 ≤ (1 - n1)
    i3 ≤ (1 - n2)
    0 ≤ i3 ≤ 1
```

This gives use three mutually exclusive indicators and the original problem can be rewritten as

```
-(1 - i1) ≤ n3 - x2 ≤ (1 - i1)
-(1 - i2) ≤ n3 - x1 ≤ (1 - i2)
-(1 - i3) ≤ n3 ≤ (1 - i3)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a more complicated one. for example : n3=x2* (n1+n2- n1*n2) +x1* (n1-n2) *(n1-n2), then how to deal with it? here all variables are all 0 or 1.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to write it out like a logic statement, like n3 is True if x2 is true AND ... Then there is a set of rule you can use to construct the linear constraints. If you can star what you want in that way I can help, but the expression you've written is too confusing to understand at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Simplify way to convert binary string to integer. And, multiply it. Is it not OK?

```
int x1 = Integer.parseInt("101011", 2);
int x2 = Integer.parseInt("00010", 2);
int x3 = Integer.parseInt("000101", 2);
int n1 = x1 * x2 * x3;
System.out.println(n1);
```

**Update**

I don't know `Gurobi`, but

```
  GRBVar x1 = model.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "x1");
  GRBVar x2 = model.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "x2");
  GRBVar x3 = model.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, "x3");
```

[Example](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.6/quick-start-guide/cs_example_mip1_cs_cs)

Comment: What I mean is used in Gurobi as a constraint